# In robots.txt - what are the directives from WBCPBlocker

Tags: web-development, robots.txt

On this site's `robots.txt` there is a comment preceding many rows of directives blocking SEO tool bots and was wondering if someone could decipher it for me.

There's the standard

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /
```

But then a comment and some things I haven't seen before:

```
# BEGIN WBCPBlocker

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "AhrefsBot" block_bot

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MJ12bot" block_bot

... 28 more rows

<Limit GET POST HEAD>

Order Allow,Deny

Allow from all

Deny from env=block_bot

</Limit>

# END WBCPBlocker
```

The main things I don't get are the "SetEnvIfNoCase", "block_bot", and the whole `<limit>` section.

Comment: You are not the only one who has seen this:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/advice-on-plugin-2/  I assume that your site is a WordPress site as well?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it is a WordPress site but I have no access to the backend. I also saw that thread but nothing definitive came from it.